# Android - Building a list of cards

Tags: android, material-design, android-cardview

I want my application to have a list of cards that users can scroll through, click actions, etc. Specifically, I want to use the `android.design.CardView` class in the support library.

As far as I'm aware, there are questions about this on SO, but it does not solve my problem. The solutions on the question I saw either say to use a list and add card-like backgrounds to each item, briefly mention `CardView`s (i.e. only mention the existence of them) or rely on a third party library.

I want to know if it is possible using only the core android API's and support libraries to vertical scrolling lists of cards either by themselves of in a `RecyclerView`. (but removing any dividers or other things that make it look like a list is behind the cards) Is this possible?

Comment: so you want each item of the recyclerview to be an actual cardview? is that right?

Comment: Or just a list of `CardView`s. Of it is in a `RecyclerView`, however, I don't just want to use a background drawable and would prefer not to use a third party library.

Comment: well you can define in your recyclerview_row_item.xml the root layout to be a CardView.....

Comment: Sure. I have several examples, such as [this one](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/RecyclerView/CardRippleList3).

Answer (score 9):

Well based on that you would like to have a List of `CardView`s....you can define in your row_layout.xml the code like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/cv">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:padding="16dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/person_photo"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/person_name"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/person_photo"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/person_age"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/person_photo"
                android:layout_below="@+id/person_name"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=" €"
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_marginLeft = "10dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/person_name"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/person_age" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Then your layout containing the RecyclerView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <include android:id="@+id/toolBar" layout="@layout/toolbar_top" app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/swipe"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and In your Adapter `CardView` can be defined as root element:

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.StockViewHolder>{

    List<Stock> stocks;

    public Adapter(List<Stock> stocks){
        this.stocks = stocks;
    }

    @Override
    public StockViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false);
        StockViewHolder pvh = new StockViewHolder(v);
        return pvh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(StockViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.stockName.setText(stocks.get(position).getName());
        holder.stockPrice.setText(stocks.get(position).getPrice());
        Ion.with(holder.stockPhoto).error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).load(stocks.get(position).getPhotoId());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return stocks.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    public static class StockViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        CardView cv;
        TextView stockName;
        TextView stockPrice;
        ImageView stockPhoto;

        StockViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cv = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
            stockName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_name);
            stockPrice = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_age);
            stockPhoto = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_photo);
        }
    }

}
```

and this will give you this result:

[image]

which is an actual list of `CardView`s.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to check out these links:

> https://github.com/Suleiman19/Masonry
>
> https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-recyclerview

The [Codepath](https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-recyclerview) guide has a very good example on how to implement the onClick on each item:

```
public class ContactsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContactsAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    // ...

    // Used to cache the views within the item layout for fast access
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        public TextView tvName;
        public TextView tvHometown;
        private Context context;

        public ViewHolder(Context context, View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.tvName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
            this.tvHometown = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvHometown);
            // Store the context
            this.context = context;
            // Attach a click listener to the entire row view
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        // Handles the row being being clicked
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int position = getLayoutPosition(); // gets item position
            User user = users.get(position);
            // We can access the data within the views
            Toast.makeText(context, tvName.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

The [Masonry](https://github.com/Suleiman19/Masonry) one is related to a more advance use of a `RecyclerView` with `CardView` (getting a `StaggeredGrid`).